# New React App deployed to Heroku Fails do to line 62 of react-dev-utils (Webpack) Jan 9, 2020

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, deployment, create-react-app

Specifically:

line 62 of ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js

> I found this:
>
> https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8079#issuecomment-562373869

I implemented the above and found that it does not fix the issue since Heroku does not use your local (edited) node_modules even after a fresh creation/deploy.

I know someone has to have a react app working on Heroku.

Please advise.

[image: Heroku Dev Page Load Error]

To Recreate:

Install prerequisites: 
git, heroku-cli, node, npm, heroku account sign-up

Note: developing on Windows 10

```
npx create-react-app app
cd app
```

test local:

```
npm start
```

or

```
heroku local web
```

follow: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#prerequisites
add engine to package.json

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.14.1",
    "npm": "6.13.4"
  }
```

Setup git repo for heroku-cli

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"

heroku login
```

follow: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku ps:scale web=1
heroku open
```

> Attempting to force Heroku's repo/cache to update the file fails to
>   solve as well:

```
git add node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js -f
git commit -m "forced edited file to repo"
git push heroku master  
heroku open
```

Answer (score 0):

After several hours and looking through some very old posts suggesting that heroku doesn't mention anything about a .gitignore file so include the whole node_modules file I decided to try adding the following to my .gitignore:

```
node_modules/*
!node_modules/react-dev-utils
```

This only allows the whole module (named: react-dev-utils) with the required edited file inside.

I'm guessing that forcing the 1 file only via git gets the whole module overridden when Heroku downloads their modules to their node_modules folder.  Therefore this blocks Heroku doing that by just including the whole module.